# Sum a column between a date range with a value cap

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to work with survey data and need to limit the rows used in a calculation based on a date range, and also the value in the column to sum needs to be capped at 2(reference cell to set limit). I don't want to use a helper column for simplicity of additional users that will be working with the file.

Assume dates are in column A, data is in column B, reference cell is F1 for cap, F2 for start date, and F3 for end date.

The array formula below is close what I need, but adding the date range has me stuck.

{=SUM(IF(Data!B:B<=F1,B:B,F1))}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MIN with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A>=F2)*(A:A<=F3)*(MIN(F1,B:B)))
```

Comment: Thank you. This would work if I wanted the sum to be no more than 2. What I'm looking to do is have each cell in B:B be no more than 2 and add all the values in the range of dates.

Comment: This is closer. The portion before the Min grabs the correct range, but min doesn't seem to create an array for sumproduct to use

Comment: @JimCole try this one.

Comment: This got me pointed in the right direction, so thank you. final formula was : =SUMPRODUCT((A:A>=F2)*(A:A<=F3),if(B:B<=F1,B:B,F1))